# Search text in JSON/Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Consider this json https://pastebin.com/wy4CmicM

I would like to search for any text within this JSON and return its corresponding json object matches in Java

For instance if I search for "**Nigel**"

The expected output must be

```
{
     "author": "Nigel Rees"
}
```

If I search for "**red**"
The expected output must be

```
[{
    "title": "Clifford, the Big Red Dog",
}, {
        "color": "red",
    }
]
```

Looking for possible ways I can tackle this problem statement, in the most efficient manner as the input JSON can get very large. Use of any external libraries are welcome as well.

Comment: Try first create a list of all objects, then try to filter the ones that match the search

Comment: If you want, i can create an implementation of the idea i wrote.